# sliding window on 3d volume matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, computer-vision, convolution, sliding-window

I need to slide a window over a 3d volume. The sliding is only on one layer of the 3d volume, i.e for each x,y with one specific z.
This is what I want to do in a loop:
   for each x,y,z, for example:

```
px =9; py =9; pz =12;

a = rand(50,50,50);
[x y z] = meshgrid(1:50,1:50,1:50);
r = 3;

%-------------loop starts here: 
% creating  a shaped window, for example sphere of radius r
inds = find((x-px).^2 + (y-py).^2 + (z-pz).^2 <= r.^2);
% getting the relevant indices, here, it is the sphere around px,py,pz
[i,j,k] = ind2sub(size(a),inds);
% adjust the center of the sphere to be at (0,0,0) instead of (px,py,pz)
adj_inds = bsxfun(@minus,[i,j,k],[px,py,pz]);

% Computing for each sphere some kind of median point
cx = sum(a(inds).*adj_inds(:,1))./sum(a(inds));
cy = sum(a(inds).*adj_inds(:,2))./sum(a(inds));
cz = sum(a(inds).*adj_inds(:,3))./sum(a(inds));

%Saving the result: the distance between the new point and the center of the sphere.
res(yc,xc) = sqrt(sum([cx,cy,cz].^2));
%-------------
```

Now, all of this should happen many many time, ( ~300000), loop takes ages, convolution returns 3d volume (for each x,y,z) while I need to perform this only for each (x,y) and a list of z's.
Help please...
Thanks
matlabit

Comment: have you tried to use column processing, using the `colfilt` function?

Comment: Well, I'm not so sure how to convert my 3d volume to a 2d input to colfilt.. I thought I could process it in layers, by my sliding window is not square, rather a sphere (or cylinder) so, each layer looks different..